# Can someone explain why I only received 1 output (24 cents) from my transaction ($3,253.29)

Tags: coinbase.com, lost-transactions, tether

Hash 0608854cc459dd9b126b20b9a605ea0ed877500a4a92e31ece6b08e3aaeaf937

I sent ($3,253.29) USDT from cryptonator to my BTC coinbase wallet and I only received 24 cents. Can somebody please explain what happened here? I'm freaking out and it was my entire savings.

### Please help!

Comment: You cannot send USDT to a BTC wallet; they are different currencies. Perhaps Coinbase also has a USDT wallet, though. This is made more confusing by the fact that USDT resides on Omni, which on its turn does use the Bitcoin blockchain - but it has nothing to do with BTC besides that, and you need separate software to send/receive that token.

Comment: Hi Shubz Kaila, I'm afraid that you will need to contact the customer support of Coinbase and/or Cryptonator. We don't have insight into what services either provide or how they operate. This community's expertise is limited to Bitcoin, we do not cover other cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score 1):

My friend,

I'm sad to tell you you might have been robbed of your money....

Cryptonator has a 2,5 stars rating. The reviews say it should not be trusted.

It seems it was split into 2 different addresses. The one where you received your cash (20 cents) and another one where they received the whole rest. This address has received well over 588 000 $ USD already. So this isn't the first time it happened. it's as if they sent you the minimum they could just to get the transaction going.

If I'm correct this address is your coinbase wallet: (value 0,20 cents)

This is the robbers wallet: (value: 588k) 163y4H32GbQSM8qgKwsDfyhmmvDnHKKaaa

In the future, use trusted exchanges such as binance, crypto.com, kraken and coinbase....

So sorry for you, sincerely...

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPx8W.png)